# Cypress switch to latest window

Tags: cypress

After clicking a button my app opens new window. 
I need to switch to the latest window. 
Currently I am using this approach (I've added Command to Cypress commands.js file) to open URL in new window, but I don't have a clue how to modify it to solve my current issue.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('openWindow', (url, features) => {
    const w = Cypress.config('viewportWidth')
    const h = Cypress.config('viewportHeight')
    if (!features) {
        features = `width=${w}, height=${h}`
    }
    console.log('openWindow %s "%s"', url, features)
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (window.top.aut) {
            console.log('window exists already')
            window.top.aut.close()
        }
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
        window.top.aut = window.top.open(url, 'aut', features)

        // letting page enough time to load and set "document.domain = localhost"
        // so we can access it
        setTimeout(() => {
            cy.state('document', window.top.aut.document);
            cy.state('window', window.top.aut);
            resolve()
        }, 500)
    }) })
```

Is there any workaround to switch between windows in Cypress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just submitted a pull request to the `cypress-open-child-window` Github Repo which adds 2 extra commands to help with this issue. `switchWindow()` and `closeWindow()`

See: https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-open-child-window/pull/4/commits/fed977edb03b8b67f934b33617867572dec0e994

In case it gets deleted, here's my forked branch:
https://github.com/jakedowns/cypress-open-child-window/tree/add-switchWindow-and-closeWindow

The gist of it is covered here, in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/jakedowns/32b75add88736fcd99c7202a98354384

**UPDATE**
here's some additional helpers I use:
https://github.com/jakedowns/CypressHelpers

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear that. I've updated my answer with a link to some other helper functions i use built around this technique for switching back and forth between multiple windows